# How to conditional resolve depedency with multiple implementation of same class read from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am writing a simple ASP.NET Core webapi. I have the `appsetting.json` with a simple configuration as below:

```
  "Providers": [
    {
      "Class": "Namespace1.Provider1",
      "Assembly": "Namespace1",
    },
    {
      "Class": "Namespace1.Provider2",
      "Assembly": "Namespace1",
    },  
  ]
```

I want to configure DI so that depending on some string type, it should take either Provider1 or Provider2 and implement the functionality accordingly.

Basically want to  know the best way to use DI with multiple implementation using same interface.

Comment: You can name registrations. That way you can register the same interface multiple times using different names. You will need to ultimately specify which name you care about for resolution purposes of course.

Comment: "depending on some string type". What is the source of that string type? Is it a piece of runtime data? Can you provide us with more background information on how you intend to use those Providers, where they need to be injected into and under which conditions you wish to select one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be using named registration, but unfortunately the built-in DI framework in ASP.NET Core does not support named registrations. So if you register multiple implementations, you are not able to tell the framework which should be selected in which cases.

However there are several 3rd party DI integrations that can allow to use this kind of functionality, you can check them [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md).

If you don't want to use any of them, then your best bet is to use the Factory registration which can let you choose what should be resolved for a service like:

```
services.AddScoped<IService>(p => new Service(new Provider1));
services.AddScoped<IAnotherService>(p => new AnotherService(new Provider2));
```

You can move your choosing logic to the appsettings like some type mapping if you like.